# Value of HashMap inside a Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have this hashmap of students which stores the id, name and last name.
So I created this :

```
Map<Interger, HashMap<String,String>> students = new HashMap<>();
```

where the second hashmap stores the name and lastname.
My goal is to look for a student in a swing application, I succeed in searching with id because it's the key of the first hashmap, but i'd like to use all of them like this:

[image]

**So my question is :** If I want to search by name or last name, how can i get the value of the first hashmap and put it in a new hashmap ?

Comment: You could maintain 3 hashmaps (id as key, name as key etc) but there's a good chance of last name / name collision, so I would iterate for name and last name. Also you really should use a `Student` object

Comment: Why do you make your own task more complex? Java is an OO language. Define classes and use them. Use a `Map<Integer, Student>` instead of storing the fields of a student in a HashMap.

Comment: I think I'll create a Student class and go from because it seems really much easier, thank you @JBNizet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on the hashmap like this :

```
private int searchByName(String s) {
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> entry : students.entrySet()) {
        HashMap student = entry.getValue(); // Hashmap containing first and lastname
        if (student.containsKey(s)) // If name match
            return entry.getKey(); // Return the student ID
    }
    return 0; // Student not found
}
```

For the lastname just use `containsValue(s)` instead of `containsKey(s)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Collections API Guava for that specifically a [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
>   containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values.

With this you'will be able to search using first name and last name. This BiMap will be value to your first parent hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the data structure is the best for your use-case but answering to your question, you should try using values() method which would return you the collection of values of the Map

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values()

```
Collection res =  studensts.values();

Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> i = res.iterator();
Map<String,String> resM = null;
while(i.hasNext()){
   resM = i.next();
}
```